# How to show page only in landscape mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, screen-rotation

This theme has a lot of posts here on the SO, but I was wondering if somone acutally find a solution.

I want to force certain page to only show in landscape mode.

How can I do that?

I am using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) script.

Comment: You mean that if someone visits your website with a portrait orientation, they see an error?

Comment: No if they visit it with a portrait mode then I need to rotate to go into landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well depending what platform/device your using..

Couldnt you do an api call like so.

```
if(approiateAPICALL.orientation == "landscape")
{
//handle land scapre
}
else
{
// handle anything else
}
```

You could handle this by checking if the width > height then its landscape
and if the height > width then its portrait...

^Not the best way but is an EXAMPLE

UPDATE:

> orientationchange timing
>
> The timing of the orientationchange with relation to the change of the
>   client height and width is different between browsers, though the
>   current implementation will give you the correct value for
>   event.orientation derived from window.orientation. This means that if
>   your bindings are dependent on the height and width values you may
>   want to disable orientationChange all together with
>   $.mobile.orientationChangeEnabled = false to let the fallback resize
>   code trigger your bindings.

Comment: hmm, I just saw that jquery mobile has a orientation events : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html , but I need some logic of how to actually rotate it

Comment: so If I set it on false then what happens?

Comment: stops the page orentation changing

Answer (score 0):

on resize, check if screens aspect ratio is greater than 1.0 (width/height), if so display your page, if not hide you page and show a message asking the user to rotate their device.

You could use a different ratio to get a wider page in proportion to the height.